# Why do many to many relation use all the key from previous table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, join

While using mysql workbench and for designing database using designer the relation tool uses a third table to form a many to many relation between 2 tables.

I have **3** tables

- **TABLE1**
- **TABLE2**
- **TABLE3**

**TABLE2** has foregin key from primary key of **TABLE1**,having a many to one relation

TABLE2 and TABLE3 are related using a many to many relation,
as soon as I create the relation
a new table TABLE3_has_TABLE2 is created with all the key from TABLE2(primarykey of table2 & foreign key of table1) and TABLE3 (primary key of table3).

Now,
why is there foreign key of table1.?

Even if i remove I will be able to query data from table1 and table3 using table2 as intermediate, so is it good to have this kind of relation or avoided?

---

For Example in below diagram
This is a geographical distribution of location, on right side it shows the hirarchy.
Now,
Table1(Zone) is the primary table i.e **Zone**
Table2(state) is related to table1 using **zone_id**
Table3(division) is related to table2(state) using **state_id** & **zone_id** of table1(zone)

Question: Should this zone_id column be in the table3 or not?

similarly table4 contains all the previous key columns of table3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice in relational models to avoid many-to-many relationships. Workbench usually compensates for user trying to do that as you have seen.

Let us use an example (or check the tl;dr), where there are two identified entities; buyers and hardware items. Some people buy 1 item, others buy more than one. The thing is, that same item can be bought by many people. So the buyer table has Mr. A buying nails. Simple enough to record in one row. But lo' and behold, he ups and gets another item! How do we show that he buys another item?

One way is by adding another attribute to the table (say "item_number_two"). But then he gets another! We can't keep going adding attributes like that. Databases were designed more for vertical addition of records, rather than horizontal addition of attributes (to give a visual picture). There is a longer explanation but you should read up, or probably might figure it out after reading this.

Another way is to re-enter a record for Mr. A and then put the ID of another item in that column, showing that he bought two items (not really "he" from a database stand-point, it's two different people!).

A better method would be to create a table that consists of the unique identifiers found in the original tables (just one per table may be necessary). This is called an intermediary table. The original tables themselves do not have foreign keys from the other table.

This is where the concept of a composite key comes in. It means that two or more candidate keys are used to uniquely identify a record rather than just one. This is how it works:

```
Person Table:
| person_ID | person_Name |
|    P0001  |    Mr. A    |
|    P0002  |    Mr. B    |
|    P0003  |    Mr. C    |
|    P0004  |    Mr. D    |

Cat Table
|   item_ID |  cat_Name   |
|    I0001  |  Nails      |
|    I0002  |  Screws     |
|    I0003  |  Hammers    |
|    I0004  |  Power-Saw  |

Intermediary table
| person_ID |   item_ID   |
|    P0001  |    I0001    |  
|    P0001  |    I0002    |
|    P0001  |    I0003    | //Shows that person 1 bought more than one item
|    P0002  |    I0004    |
|    P0002  |    I0001    | //Shows that an item has been bought by more that one person
```

So this new table matches a record of one table(through the use of a primary key) to a record of another. The only thing that will ever be repeated is one of the two ID's. A unique record is made as long as no two combinations are repeated.

tl;dr - Having tables mapped in a many to many relationship inevitably wastes space in the DB when entering records, as new records of the same data have to be made to show a small difference (adding no real value in proportion to the space). Another issue is that it causes more calculations than necessary when a query is made, wasting time and space. Or the results returned may just be plain wrong...

EDIT:
If you have tables A and B having a many-to-many relationship, do the following as an alternative. Create a table C. Take the primary keys from table A and B and place them in tables C. In table C they both exist as primary and foreign keys. This would mean the following relationship is created.

```
| Table A |-----------<| Table C |>------------|Table B|
```

Table A and B are linked through C.

Sample query:

```
SELECT C.itemID FROM A, C WHERE A.personID = P0001 AND A.personID = C.personID;
```

This query will return all ID's of the items bought by the person with an ID of P0001. Records must match the condition of having a personID of P0001, but the record selected must have that matching ID in Table C (the intermediary table). An extended query could be to take the item names from the Table B. Each attribute in C has a recorded value that corresponds to a value of a key in either Table A or B, meaning that a query can be run to pull other info, where the value in Table C is = to the values in Table A/B (depending on which one you want).

Comment: 1.What could be the alternative of using a many to many relation?

Comment: The intermediary table I mentioned. Check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly from a denormalization point-of-view, the DIVISION.STATE_ZONE_ID isn't required.

Since you can get the ZONE_ID from the DIVISION by joining STATE on the state_id.

And it's the same with the division_state_state_id & division_state_zone_id in DISTRICT.
Having the division_division_id is enough to join DIVISION, then STATE, then ZONE.

However, what if you would remove those 'extra' fields?
Then a SQL always needs to go through that cascade of joined tables to get the ZONE.zone_name.

So there's an advantage that by having those 'extra' fields, it becomes possible to JOIN directly to the ZONE table. Which can simplify/speed up certain popular queries.

The disadvantage is that it becomes harder to assure referential integrity.
Because for example, you could assign a different zone_id to a DIVISION.state_zone_id than the STATE.zone_id you can get via  DIVISION.state_state_id.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was also thinking, is there any way to ensure that referential integrity is maintained. Because I am facing this issue that you mentioned of joining multiple tables and slowing the query.

Comment: It's commonly done via [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) on the tables involved. For example, when you update DISTRINCT.division_division_id then an update trigger automatically retrieves the correct zone_id from DIVISION and then also corrects the DISTRINCT.division_state_zone_id. It gets harder when STATE.zone_id is changed, and an after update trigger then needs to correct all other tables accordingly.